# Why python server not able to receive and send messages?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, server

I have a chatbot in python and want to integrate it to my react website. I am getting the following error while sending data to python server at localhost:/5000 from localhost:/3000:

```
 Could not proxy request /js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.
```

The code for my python and js file:

```
from flask import Flask
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/members")
def members():
    return {"members":["Member1","Member2","Member3"]}

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The message file:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import './Message.css';
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
const Message=()=>
{
    // state ={
    //     chat:[],
    //     msg:''
    // }
    const [chat,setChat]=useState(["hellos zdfgzsdfgsfdg","dfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgs","sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg"]);
    const [msg,setMsg]=useState("");
    const[data,setData]=useState([{}])

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch("/members").then(
            res=>res.json()
        ).then(
            data=>{
                setData(data)
                console.log(data)
            }
        )
    },[])
    return(
            <div  >
                
            </div>
        )
    
}
export default Message;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/members`).then(.......
```

REACT_APP_API='http://localhost:8000'   for example